# Magento 2 override paypal ipn in custom module

Tags: magento2

I want to override PayPal Ipn.php file at location vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Ipn.php in the custom module.

I have done by adding preference in di.xml file. But i am not getting `$incrementId = $this->getRequestData('invoice');` in `protected function _getOrder()` . Please help!

```
<preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Ipn" type="Company\PaypalOrderErrorLog\Model\Ipn" />
```

And

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Stream\PaypalOrderErrorLog\Model;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

/**
 * PayPal Instant Payment Notification processor model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Ipn extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Ipn
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    protected $_order;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $_orderFactory;

    /**
     * PayPal info instance
     *
     * @var Info
     */
    protected $_paypalInfo;

    /**
     * @var OrderSender
     */
    protected $orderSender;

    /**
     * @var CreditmemoSender
     */
    protected $creditmemoSender;

    protected $_paypalOrderErrorLogFactory;

    protected $_storeResolver;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\ConfigFactory $configFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\CurlFactory $curlFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Paypal\Model\Info $paypalInfo,
        OrderSender $orderSender,
        CreditmemoSender $creditmemoSender,
        \Company\PaypalOrderErrorLog\Model\PaypalOrderErrorLogFactory $paypalOrderErrorLogFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver $storeResolver
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $configFactory, 
            $logger, 
            $curlFactory, 
            $orderFactory, 
            $paypalInfo, 
            $orderSender, 
            $creditmemoSender
        );
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
        $this->_paypalInfo = $paypalInfo;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->creditmemoSender = $creditmemoSender;
        $this->_paypalOrderErrorLogFactory = $paypalOrderErrorLogFactory;
        $this->_storeResolver = $storeResolver;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Get ipn data, send verification to PayPal, run corresponding handler
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function processIpnRequest()
    {
        $this->_addDebugData('ipn', $this->getRequestData());

        try {
            $this->_getConfig();
            $this->_postBack();
            $this->_processOrder();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_addDebugData('exception', $e->getMessage());
            $this->_debug();
            throw $e;
        }
        $this->_debug();
    }

    /**
     * Get config with the method code and store id and validate
     *
     * @return \Magento\Paypal\Model\Config
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _getConfig()
    {
        $order = $this->_getOrder();
        $methodCode = $order->getPayment()->getMethod();
        $parameters = ['params' => [$methodCode, $order->getStoreId()]];
        $this->_config = $this->_configFactory->create($parameters);
        if (!$this->_config->isMethodActive($methodCode) || !$this->_config->isMethodAvailable()) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Method "%s" is not available.', $methodCode));
        }
        /** @link https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro */
        // verify merchant email intended to receive notification
        $merchantEmail = $this->_config->getValue('businessAccount');
        if (!$merchantEmail) {
            return $this->_config;
        }
        $receiver = $this->getRequestData('business') ?: $this->getRequestData('receiver_email');
        if (strtolower($merchantEmail) != strtolower($receiver)) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf('The requested %s and configured %s merchant emails do not match.', $receiver, $merchantEmail)
            );
        }

        return $this->_config;
    }

    /**
     * Load order
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _getOrder()
    {
        $incrementId = $this->getRequestData('invoice');
        $this->_order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
        if (!$this->_order->getId()) {

            /*********  CUSTOM LOG SAVE  **************/
            try {
                $data = [
                    'order_id' => $incrementId,
                    'store_id' => $this->getCurrentStoreId(),
                    'customer_email' => $this->getRequestData('payer_email'),
                ];
                $rowData = $this->_paypalOrderErrorLogFactory->create();
                $rowData->setData($data);
                $rowData->save();
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                $this->_logger->critical($ex->getMessage());
            }
            /*********  CUSTOM LOG SAVE ENDS **************/

            throw new Exception(sprintf('Wrong order ID: "%s".', $incrementId));
        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    /**
     * IPN workflow implementation
     * Everything should be added to order comments. In positive processing cases customer will get email notifications.
     * Admin will be notified on errors.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _processOrder()
    {
        $this->_getConfig();
        try {
            // Handle payment_status
            $transactionType = $this->getRequestData('txn_type');
            switch ($transactionType) {
                // handle new case created
                case Info::TXN_TYPE_NEW_CASE:
                    $this->_registerDispute();
                    break;
                // handle new adjustment is created
                case Info::TXN_TYPE_ADJUSTMENT:
                    $this->_registerAdjustment();
                    break;
                //handle new transaction created
                default:
                    $this->_registerTransaction();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $comment = $this->_createIpnComment(__('Note: %1', $e->getMessage()), true);
            $comment->save();
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process dispute notification
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerDispute()
    {
        $reasonComment = $this->_paypalInfo->explainReasonCode($this->getRequestData('reason_code'));
        $caseType = $this->getRequestData('case_type');
        $caseTypeLabel = $this->_paypalInfo->getCaseTypeLabel($caseType);
        $caseId = $this->getRequestData('case_id');
        //Add IPN comment about registered dispute
        $message = __(
            'IPN "%1". Case type "%2". Case ID "%3" %4',
            ucfirst($caseType),
            $caseTypeLabel,
            $caseId,
            $reasonComment
        );
        $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($message)->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->save();
    }

    /**
     * Process adjustment notification
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerAdjustment()
    {
        $reasonCode = $this->getRequestData('reason_code');
        $reasonComment = $this->_paypalInfo->explainReasonCode($reasonCode);
        $notificationAmount = $this->_order->getBaseCurrency()->formatTxt($this->getRequestData('mc_gross'));
        // Add IPN comment about registered dispute
        $message = __(
            'IPN "%1". A dispute has been resolved and closed. %2 Transaction amount %3.',
            ucfirst($reasonCode),
            $notificationAmount,
            $reasonComment
        );
        $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($message)->setIsCustomerNotified(false)->save();
    }

    /**
     * Process regular IPN notifications
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws Exception
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    protected function _registerTransaction()
    {
        // Handle payment_status
        $paymentStatus = $this->_filterPaymentStatus($this->getRequestData('payment_status'));
        switch ($paymentStatus) {
            // paid
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_COMPLETED:
                $this->_registerPaymentCapture(true);
                break;
            // the holded payment was denied on paypal side
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_DENIED:
                $this->_registerPaymentDenial();
                break;
            // customer attempted to pay via bank account, but failed
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_FAILED:
                // cancel order
                $this->_registerPaymentFailure();
                break;
            // payment was obtained, but money were not captured yet
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_PENDING:
                $this->_registerPaymentPending();
                break;
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_PROCESSED:
                $this->_registerMasspaymentsSuccess();
                break;
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_REVERSED:
                //break is intentionally omitted
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_UNREVERSED:
                $this->_registerPaymentReversal();
                break;
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_REFUNDED:
                $this->_registerPaymentRefund();
                break;
            // authorization expire/void
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_EXPIRED:
                // break is intentionally omitted
            case Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_VOIDED:
                $this->_registerPaymentVoid();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Cannot handle payment status '{$paymentStatus}'.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process completed payment (either full or partial)
     *
     * @param bool $skipFraudDetection
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentCapture($skipFraudDetection = false)
    {
        if ($this->getRequestData('transaction_entity') == 'auth') {
            return;
        }
        $parentTransactionId = $this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id');
        $this->_importPaymentInformation();
        $payment = $this->_order->getPayment();
        $payment->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'));
        $payment->setCurrencyCode($this->getRequestData('mc_currency'));
        $payment->setPreparedMessage($this->_createIpnComment(''));
        $payment->setParentTransactionId($parentTransactionId);
        $payment->setShouldCloseParentTransaction('Completed' === $this->getRequestData('auth_status'));
        $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(0);
        $payment->registerCaptureNotification(
            $this->getRequestData('mc_gross'),
            $skipFraudDetection && $parentTransactionId
        );
        $this->_order->save();

        // notify customer
        $invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice();
        if ($invoice && !$this->_order->getEmailSent()) {
            $this->orderSender->send($this->_order);
            $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('You notified customer about invoice #%1.', $invoice->getIncrementId())
            )
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                ->save();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process denied payment notification
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentDenial()
    {
        try {
            $this->_importPaymentInformation();
            $this->_order->getPayment()
                ->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'))
                ->setNotificationResult(true)
                ->setIsTransactionClosed(true)
                ->deny(false);
            $this->_order->save();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($e->getMessage() != __('We cannot cancel this order.')) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Treat failed payment as order cancellation
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentFailure()
    {
        $this->_importPaymentInformation();
        $this->_order->registerCancellation($this->_createIpnComment(''))->save();
    }

    /**
     * Process payment pending notification
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function _registerPaymentPending()
    {
        $reason = $this->getRequestData('pending_reason');
        if ('authorization' === $reason) {
            $this->_registerPaymentAuthorization();
            return;
        }

        // case when was placed using PayPal standard
        if (\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT == $this->_order->getState()
            && !$this->getRequestData('transaction_entity')
        ) {
            $this->_registerPaymentCapture();
            return;
        }

        $this->_importPaymentInformation();

        $this->_order->getPayment()
            ->setPreparedMessage(
                $this->_createIpnComment($this->_paypalInfo->explainPendingReason($reason))
            )
            ->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'))
            ->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
            ->update(false);
        $this->_order->save();
    }

    /**
     * Register authorized payment
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentAuthorization()
    {
        /** @var $payment \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment */
        $payment = $this->_order->getPayment();
        if ($this->_order->canFetchPaymentReviewUpdate()) {
            $payment->update(true);
        } else {
            $this->_importPaymentInformation();
            $payment->setPreparedMessage($this->_createIpnComment(''))
                ->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'))
                ->setParentTransactionId($this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id'))
                ->setCurrencyCode($this->getRequestData('mc_currency'))
                ->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
                ->registerAuthorizationNotification($this->getRequestData('mc_gross'));
        }
        if (!$this->_order->getEmailSent()) {
            $this->orderSender->send($this->_order);
        }
        $this->_order->save();
    }

    /**
     * The status "Processed" is used when all Masspayments are successful
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerMasspaymentsSuccess()
    {
        $comment = $this->_createIpnComment('', true);
        $comment->save();
    }

    /**
     * Process payment reversal and cancelled reversal notification
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentReversal()
    {
        $reasonCode = $this->getRequestData('reason_code');
        $reasonComment = $this->_paypalInfo->explainReasonCode($reasonCode);
        $notificationAmount = $this->_order->getBaseCurrency()
            ->formatTxt(
                $this->getRequestData('mc_gross') + $this->getRequestData('mc_fee')
            );
        $paymentStatus = $this->_filterPaymentStatus($this->getRequestData('payment_status'));
        $orderStatus = $paymentStatus ==
        Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_REVERSED ? Info::ORDER_STATUS_REVERSED : Info::ORDER_STATUS_CANCELED_REVERSAL;
        //Change order status to PayPal Reversed/PayPal Cancelled Reversal if it is possible.
        $message = __(
            'IPN "%1". %2 Transaction amount %3. Transaction ID: "%4"',
            $this->getRequestData('payment_status'),
            $reasonComment,
            $notificationAmount,
            $this->getRequestData('txn_id')
        );
        $this->_order->setStatus($orderStatus);
        $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($message, $orderStatus)
            ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)
            ->save();
    }

    /**
     * Process a refund
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentRefund()
    {
        $this->_importPaymentInformation();
        $reason = $this->getRequestData('reason_code');
        $isRefundFinal = !$this->_paypalInfo->isReversalDisputable($reason);
        $payment = $this->_order->getPayment()
            ->setPreparedMessage(
                $this->_createIpnComment($this->_paypalInfo->explainReasonCode($reason))
            )
            ->setTransactionId($this->getRequestData('txn_id'))
            ->setParentTransactionId($this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id'))
            ->setIsTransactionClosed($isRefundFinal)
            ->registerRefundNotification(-1 * $this->getRequestData('mc_gross'));
        $this->_order->save();

        // TODO: there is no way to close a capture right now

        $creditMemo = $payment->getCreatedCreditmemo();
        if ($creditMemo) {
            $this->creditmemoSender->send($creditMemo);
            $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('You notified customer about creditmemo #%1.', $creditMemo->getIncrementId())
            )
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                ->save();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process voided authorization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _registerPaymentVoid()
    {
        $this->_importPaymentInformation();

        $parentTxnId = $this->getRequestData('transaction_entity') == 'auth'
            ? $this->getRequestData('txn_id')
            : $this->getRequestData('parent_txn_id');

        $this->_order->getPayment()
            ->setPreparedMessage($this->_createIpnComment(''))
            ->setParentTransactionId($parentTxnId)
            ->registerVoidNotification();

        $this->_order->save();
    }

    /**
     * Map payment information from IPN to payment object
     * Returns true if there were changes in information
     *
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    protected function _importPaymentInformation()
    {
        $payment = $this->_order->getPayment();
        $was = $payment->getAdditionalInformation();

        // collect basic information
        $from = [];
        foreach ([
                     Info::PAYER_ID,
                     'payer_email' => Info::PAYER_EMAIL,
                     Info::PAYER_STATUS,
                     Info::ADDRESS_STATUS,
                     Info::PROTECTION_EL,
                     Info::PAYMENT_STATUS,
                     Info::PENDING_REASON,
                 ] as $privateKey => $publicKey) {
            if (is_int($privateKey)) {
                $privateKey = $publicKey;
            }
            $value = $this->getRequestData($privateKey);
            if ($value) {
                $from[$publicKey] = $value;
            }
        }
        if (isset($from['payment_status'])) {
            $from['payment_status'] = $this->_filterPaymentStatus($this->getRequestData('payment_status'));
        }

        // collect fraud filters
        $fraudFilters = [];
        for ($i = 1; $value = $this->getRequestData("fraud_management_pending_filters_{$i}"); $i++) {
            $fraudFilters[] = $value;
        }
        if ($fraudFilters) {
            $from[Info::FRAUD_FILTERS] = $fraudFilters;
        }

        $this->_paypalInfo->importToPayment($from, $payment);

        /**
         * Detect pending payment, frauds
         * TODO: implement logic in one place
         * @see \Magento\Paypal\Model\Pro::importPaymentInfo()
         */
        if (Info::isPaymentReviewRequired($payment)) {
            $payment->setIsTransactionPending(true);
            if ($fraudFilters) {
                $payment->setIsFraudDetected(true);
            }
        }
        if (Info::isPaymentSuccessful($payment)) {
            $payment->setIsTransactionApproved(true);
        } elseif (Info::isPaymentFailed($payment)) {
            $payment->setIsTransactionDenied(true);
        }

        return $was != $payment->getAdditionalInformation();
    }

    /**
     * Generate an "IPN" comment with additional explanation.
     * Returns the generated comment or order status history object
     *
     * @param string $comment
     * @param bool $addToHistory
     * @return string|\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History
     */
    protected function _createIpnComment($comment = '', $addToHistory = false)
    {
        $message = __('IPN "%1"', $this->getRequestData('payment_status'));
        if ($comment) {
            $message .= ' ' . $comment;
        }
        if ($addToHistory) {
            $message = $this->_order->addStatusHistoryComment($message);
            $message->setIsCustomerNotified(null);
        }
        return $message;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current store id, if it can be detected or default store id
     * 
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getCurrentStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code .

Comment: @SohelRana updated the question.